# Tree view из JSON

Tags: python, django

На  django-фронтенд приходит Json в виде дерева. Например, вот такое.
`{
    "compiler": {
        "type": "GCC",
        "version": "5.4"
    },
    "cpu": {
        "architecture": "x86_64",
        "count": 4
    }
}`

Что нужно сделать, чтобы отобразить это дерево визуально?
Что-то вроде такой библиотеки https://github.com/lmenezes/json-tree , но на django.

Comment: На какой ОС работаете?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04, если это важно в этом вопросе.

Comment: попробуйте этот вариант, я сам django не пользуюсь. Но есть куча надстроек которые делают визуалтзацию json для разных программ/фреймворков https://github.com/jsocol/django-jsonview

Comment: Может быть эта статья поможет https://www.pydanny.com/pretty-formatting-json-django-admin.html

Comment: @djkah11, приходит это как понимать? Если подтягивается скриптом с другого ресурса, то рендер через js, например vue.js. Если формируем через python, то преобразуем в массив и передаем в шаблон. Уточните задачу.

Comment: Я посылаю запрос из django на бекенд и мне приходит ответ в виде Json.

Comment: Отобразить визуально? Смотря что под этим подразумевать. Можно отобразить визуально на разный манер: В виде картинки, в виде html... Можно вообще вернуть в том же виде, что приняли - тоже отображение. Вопрос риторический, какой Вы ответ хотели получить?

Comment: Я бы хотел увидеть что-то напоминающее дерево. В виде картинки или в виде html  - не важно.